# Angular 4: Passing a function as a parameter to a component in the template

Tags: angular, typescript

In AngularJS it's possible to pass a function signature to a component attribute and call the function from inside the component, conforming the parameters to the correct signature.

Effectively, this is like assigning an event handler from a parent component to a child component's event, but inside of the HTML template instead of in the controller's JS code.

Is there an equivalent way (or altogether better approach) to do this in Angular 4? Maybe there is just an alternate syntax for the same thing, I am not sure,

HTML:

```
<app-component onTrigger="doSomethingOnTrigger(id, args)">
</app-component>
```

JS (in the child's controller the arguments must be passed as a single object):

```
vm.onTrigger({ id: id, args: args });
```

Where the binding definition looks like this,

```
.component("appComponent", {
        bindings: {
            onTrigger: "&"
```

Thank you!

Comment: `<app-component [onTrigger]="callMeBack">`  where `callMeBack` is the function to pass in the parent component and `onTrigger` is the variable name of the function in the `app-component` component.

Comment: Thanks, thought I already tried this, but it works! Not sure what I missed the first time. Super easy.